# Parse input value to php variable on submit (clashing with other scripts running)

Tags: php

I have a form that's doing various other things on top of what I want it to do, not an ideal situation but I want to tag on some extra things.

Is it possible to parse the email input field into a php variable on submit without breaking what's currently there? And then fire the php below the form?

```
  <form action="/event" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="event" value="mc_newsletter_add">
    <input type="hidden" name="data[source]" value="newsletter">
    <input checked=checked type="checkbox" name="data[newsletter_onetime]" id="newsletter_onetime" class="newsletter-optins">
    <input checked=checked type="checkbox" name="data[promos]" id="promos" class="newsletter-optins">

    <input class="modal-newsletter-input" id="EmailAddress" name="data[customers_email_address]" placeholder="Enter your email here" required="required" type="email" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['email'])){echo $_GET['email'];}?>" aria-required="true">
    <input class="modal-newsletter-signup" id="newslettersignup" onclick="register_signup();" name="Submit" type="submit" value="Yes, sign me up" />
  </form>
```

Here's the php:

```
<?php $sib_tracking = new SIB_Tracking();
      $email = (submitted email to go here);
      $event = "marketing";
      $result = $sib_tracking->track_event($email, $event); ?>
```

Comment: So what's the problem with adding your code to code which processes form submit?

Comment: @u_mulder It'll clash with the other stuff running, I need to fire it's own function. How can I add an extra function in on submit and pull in the submitted email address?

Comment: How it will clash? You can invent something like ajax query to your script, but still I don't understand the problem of adding 3-4 lines of code.

Comment: @u_mulder There's other forms that call the same function. I want to call a different one so it'll only run once for this form.

Comment: So call a different function, then. If there is shared functionality then that could potentially be put into another function to be called from more than one place. Or maybe you just need an if statement or something. Hard to give precise advice without seeing or understanding more code/context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't sure whats your `register_signup()` do. I assume it's a hook of some kind.

So what you can do, on click event - prevent form submitting. Send form data via `$ajax` request, then call your hook `register_signup()`, then remove the form from page to prevent further duplicated submitting.

```
  <form action="/event" method="POST" id="signupForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="event" value="mc_newsletter_add">
    <input type="hidden" name="data[source]" value="newsletter">
    <input checked=checked type="checkbox" name="data[newsletter_onetime]" id="newsletter_onetime" class="newsletter-optins">
    <input checked=checked type="checkbox" name="data[promos]" id="promos" class="newsletter-optins">

    <input class="modal-newsletter-input" id="EmailAddress" name="data[customers_email_address]" placeholder="Enter your email here" required="required" type="email" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['email'])){echo $_GET['email'];}?>" aria-required="true">
    <input class="modal-newsletter-signup" id="newslettersignup" name="Submit" type="submit" value="Yes, sign me up" />
  </form>

  <script>
    $("#signupForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);

        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: form.attr('action'),
               data: form.serialize(),
               success: function(data)
               {
                   console.log(data); //data contain response from your php script
                   register_signup();
                   form.replaceWith("<div>You signed in</div>"); //This is optional - remove your form from page
               }
             });
    });
  </script>
```

Be aware - I add `id` to `<form>` tag, and remove `onClick` handler and submit button.

Hope that what you looking for.

Comment: Ok this has got me a bit further but changes the scope of the question a bit now. I need to figure out how to parse the data into the php block which I'll ask as a separate question.